# Why is bitwise OR operation not working as expected when an unsigned char is ORed with 11100000?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I am not able to understand why the operation 'c | 11100000' does not seem to work. But I also noticed that 'c | 10000000' works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c, c1;
    
    c = c & 0;
    c = c | 11100000;
    printf("%o \t", c);
    
    /** prints 140 ***/
    
    
    c = c & 0;
    c = c | 111;
    c << 5;
    printf("%o", c);
    
    /** prints 157 **/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `11100000` is a decimal numeral for eleven million and one hundred thousand. Did you expect it to be a binary numeral for two hundred and twenty four?

Comment: I was trying to encode a UTF8 character.

Comment: Why are you using Octal ?

Comment: user994886, If you expect `"340"` as the octal output, consider an octal constant `c = c | 0340;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant values that you are using are in decimal format, not binary.

C doesn't support binary constants, but it does support hex constants:

```
c = c | 0xe0;
...
c = c | 0x7;
```

Also, this doesn't do anything:

```
c << 5;
```

Presumably, you want:

```
c = c << 5;
```

Comment: Thanks.  corrected it to c = c << 5;

Comment: C doesn't support binary constants but some compilers have it as an extension: `c | 0b11100000`

Comment: As a side note I believe binary constants have been proposed for the upcoming C2x. I guess the people in the committee never programmed 32 bit or larger CPUs... I so look forward to `MY_REGISTER = 0b00111011010100110001100111100011;` Because magic numbers in hex wasn't bad enough, I guess?

Comment: `c <<= 5;` would also do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the confusion is that you think that this integer constant  `11100000` represents a binary literal. That is 1 and 0 are bit values.

However if you will execute this statement

```
printf( "11100000 = %x\n", 11100000 );
```

you will see that the hexadecimal representation of the constant is `a95f60`

```
11100000 = a95f60
```

So in this statement

```
c = c | 11100000;
```

the less significant byte that is equal to `0x60` (or in decimal `96`) is assigned to the variable `c`.

It is not the same if to write

```
c = c | 111;
c <<= 5;
```

Moreover pay attention to that this expression statement

```
c << 5;
```

does not have an effect. It seems you mean

```
c <<= 5;
```

that is equivalent to the multiplication of the decimal value `111` by `32` and again assigning the less significant byte to the variable `c`.

If you will execute this statement

```
printf( "111 << 5 = %d\n", 111 << 5 );
```

then you will see that the result is

```
111 << 5 = 3552
```

As it is seen `3552` is not the same as `11100000`.

So the output of this statement

```
c = 111 << 5;
printf( "%d\n", c);
```

is decimal `224`.

Opposite to C++ in C there are no integer binary constants.

In C++ there are binary literals and you could obtain the expected result running this program

```
#include <cstdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    c = c | 0b11'100'000;
    printf( "%o\t", c );

    c = 0b111;
    c <<= 5;
    printf( "%o\n", c );
}
```

The program output is

```
340     340
```